# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Model' PySB

Tags: attributeerror

I have just install PySB and trying to make it work. I run the example attached with downloaded documantation but it does not work.

```
import pysb as psb
from pysb.integrate import odesolve as psb
from pylab import linspace, plot, xlabel, ylabel, show:   

psb.Model()

# Declare the monomers
psb.Monomer('L', ['s'])
psb.Monomer('R', ['s'])

# Declare the parameters
psb.Parameter('L_0', 100)
psb.Parameter('R_0', 200)
psb.Parameter('kf', 1e-3)
psb.Parameter('kr', 1e-3)

# Declare the initial conditions
psb.Initial(L(s=None), L_0)
psb.Initial(R(s=None), R_0)

# Declare the binding rule
psb.Rule('L_binds_R', L(s=None) + R(s=None) <> L(s=1) % R(s=1), kf, kr)

# Observe the complex
psb.Observable('LR', L(s=1) % R(s=1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print __doc__
    # Simulate the model through 40 seconds
    time = linspace(0, 40, 100)
    print "Simulating..."
    x = psb.odesolve(model, time)
    # Plot the trajectory of LR
    plot(time, x['LR'])
    xlabel('Time (seconds)')
    ylabel('Amount of LR')
    show()
```

The first error I have is at `psb.odesolve()`:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

Could you advise?
Thanks

I tried code from the pysb.org and I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruda\Desktop\t2.py", line 33, in <module>
    x = odesolve(model, time)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysb\integrate.py", line 298, in odesolve
    solver = Solver(model, tspan, integrator, **integrator_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysb\integrate.py", line 86, in __init__
    pysb.bng.generate_equations(model)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysb\bng.py", line 261, in generate_equations
    lines = iter(generate_network(model).split('\n'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysb\bng.py", line 220, in generate_network
    bng_file = open(bng_filename, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: '<interactive>_5136_5952_temp.bngl'
```

Comment: Full stacktrace. Concise example.

Comment: What does it mean??? Could you be more specific?

Comment: The traceback is everything from the line that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the line with the actual exception.  The intermediate steps can often provide clues that are not obvious from just the exception message itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have minor syntax errors and different imports compared to the example at http://pysb.org/.  Also, the PySB documentation says that you have to do:

```
from pysb import *
Model()
```

to initialize things, and that construct then apparently creates a `model` variable in your module's namespace.  I suggest copying the pysb sample exactly as is and verify that it works properly before you start tweaking it.

Comment: Hi Fredrik, I took the example from pysb.org and the results is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

PySB developer here.

The problem is the following:

```
import pysb as psb
from pysb.integrate import odesolve as psb
psb.Model()
```

You've imported pysb as "psb", but then you've imported the function odesolve *also as psb*. Hence when you call psb.Model(), it's trying to call the class constructor "Model" on the function odesolve. This is why it's giving the error "'function' object has no attribute 'Model'".

For the sake of this example, I would recommend just doing

```
from pysb import *
from pysb.integrate import odesolve
```

and removing the psb qualifiers in front of the Component constructors.

Also, I recommend signing up for the pysb mailing list by emailing pysb@librelist.org! We can respond to your questions promptly there. Let us know if you have any other questions.

Best,

John Bachman

Answer (score 0):

Another PySB developer here. John Bachman is right -- in your original code, your first import, `import pysb as psb` is shadowed by the second one, `from pysb.integrate import odesolve as psb`. Just delete the `as psb` in the second line and change `psb.odesolve` below to `odesolve`. Also there is an extraneous colon at the end of the third line which needs to be deleted. I fixed those issues and the code runs fine.

Regarding the error you got with the example code from the pysb.org home page, it looks like you've pasted the code into an interactive python session. There is unfortunately a bug with running odesolve() in that context. Try saving the example code to a .py file and running it from the command line. The bug will be fixed in the next PySB release.